# Is 3 hours enough connecting time in New Delhi Indira Gandhi (T1 to T3)?

Tags: air-travel, transit, del, pnq

Recently my GoAir flight from Nagpur to New Delhi was cancelled. I have an international flight (Emirates) from New Delhi International Airport. The other options GoAir people are giving me is of another flight which is not a direct flight but via Pune. The GoAir flight is expected to arrive at Delhi Domestic Airport at 00:45 AM and my international flight's departure time is 04:00 AM. I am wondering is 3 hours enough for me to move from Domestic to International airport?

Can I ask the airline people to book my flight in other airlines as the flight got cancelled and it's their fault?

Comment: @pnuts you've proposed an edit which I originally did (changing Delhi to Pune) but after re-reading I'm not sure it is.  It looks like he was going from Nagpur to Delhi, THEN flying international, and now is going from Nagpur via Pune to Delhi, THEN flying international. So the connecting time is still in New Delhi.

Comment: @pnuts Yes but (Was it you?) the edit suggested changing the title from 'New Delhi' to 'Pune' airport? That was my worry :/

Comment: @John it'd really help if you could clarify

Comment: @pnuts Very odd.  Well I can't edit it now as it's still waiting @ reviews from others, but when it's done I'll add in the tag and other suggestions you gave.

Comment: I am going from Nagpur to NewDelhi. But because of non stop flight cancellation from Nagpur to NewDelhi, there is another flight which GoAir is recommending me which is not a non stop flight. It goes to Pune first from Nagpur and then from Pune to New Delhi (00:45 Arrival).

Comment: @John so are you asking about the connection time in Pune or New Delhi?

Comment: This GoAir Airline is really weird. They now cancelled my Nagpur-Pune-NewDelhi flight as well.I got a text message and email 24 hrs before. Also while refunding, they are not ready to refund 100/- convenience charges. Now, I have booked my tickets with another airline which will arrive at NewDelhi in the afternoon and hence I don't have at least worry about 3 hours time.

Comment: I live near IGI and trust me, 3 hours is a lot of time :)

Answer (score 5):

It's enough time *if* all goes according to plan.  However, you've got very little buffer if anything goes wrong, and going via another airport means the odds of something going wrong are multiplied.  **Personally, I would not risk it**.

Unfortunately your options are limited here.  GoAir is a low-cost carrier and you've booked your connecting international flight yourself: they're responsible for getting you to Delhi, but whether or not you make the connection is not their problem, so they're very unlikely to be willing to pay to put you on a different airline.

In your shoes, I would either:

1. Ask them to transfer you to a flight that gets you to Delhi *much* earlier, eg. the previous day, or
2. Ask them to refund the money for your cancelled flight, and book a direct flight on a different airline, paying the cost yourself.

Comment: `going via another airport` -- did you mean another terminal here?

Comment: Yup.  (Although the different terminals at Delhi don't help either.)

Answer (score 2):

You have enough time it hardly takes 15 to 20 minutes to go from `T1C to T3` and the check-in counter closes only before 90 minutes and there is also a Shuttle transfer between `T1C to T3` every 1/2 hour you just have to produce

- Boarding pass
- Onward Journey Ticket

Comment: You didn't mention security checks and passport control. How long will the queue at passport control be? Is it possible to change from T1 to T3 airside, or will one be required to pass security again?