# Action against GoAir airline

Tags: legal, cancellations, goair

Referring to [Is 3 hours enough connecting time in New Delhi Indira Gandhi (T1 to T3)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37931/is-3-hours-enough-connecting-time-in-new-delhi-indira-gandhi-t1-to-t3/37938#37938) the following thread and my last comment, which is as follows:

> This GoAir Airline is really weird. They now cancelled my Nagpur-Pune-NewDelhi flight as well.I got a text message and email 24 hrs before. Also while refunding, they are not ready to refund 100/- convenience charges. Now, I have booked my tickets with another airline which will arrive at New Delhi in the afternoon and hence I don't have at least worry about 3 hours time.

I am planning to take some action against this nonsense GoAir airline company because of which I had to pay Rs 10,000 for the new flight because of an eleventh hour cancellation.

Can anyone suggest if someone has taken any sort of action before?

Comment: This now becomes a legal action question, rather than travel :/ Not sure we're going to able to help.

Comment: This question appears to be a legal action question, and not within the scope of travel.SE.

Comment: @pnuts, no..but not everything is. Not that it's the same extreme, but for example, we don't explicitly forbid questions on dinosaurs, but they'd be off-topic as they're not in the scope - which is travel.  His original question was a travel problem about connecting times in an airport - now it's a legal one - the travel part is over, and he's asking about taking legal action. That's my view anyway, but there's a reason we vote as a community :)

Comment: Sigh...extinct giant lizards are not animations and theme parks...and you *know* that wasn't the point of the example. Feel free to continue in [chat], I'm done in the comments.

Comment: "Action" does not have to be *legal* action, writing to a newspaper, consumer protection agency, etc might also work.  Although, quite frankly, since you've gotten your money back (delta Rs. 100), it's unlikely there's anything anybody can do for you.

Answer (score 5):

Airlines reserve the right to change or cancel flights and spell out their responsibilities in the terms & conditions of your booking.  But 99% of us don't bother reviewing this, we simply buy the ticket and check whatever boxes they tell us to.  You should read their terms & conditions and Contract of Carriage first, before deciding to spend money on a lawyer.

Why did the airline cancel your flight?  Weather, mechanical issue, route being dropped? Depending on the reason, your avenues of recourse may vary. But in the long run, they cancelled, they offered a refund, end of responsibility.

What is "100/- convenience charges" (I am guessing the first is 100%)? So what convenience charges are they not refunding?  If they cancel they should refund airfare, any advance paid baggage, seat or food charges.  Charges such as a call center agent fee (which some carriers now charge) would not be part of this, as you got the service you paid for.  A caring airline would likely refund this, but they wouldn't be required to.

Comment: Then that would fall into the same category as my call center fee example, a non-refundable charge because the OP did use the system.

Comment: "Non-refundable" here should apply to *passengers* who cancel, but if it's the airline cancelling, they should be refunding *all* fees.  But this is India...